# Join questionn - Select must return only one record

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have 4 tables in my SQL Server 2008 database :

- CONTACT
- CONTACT_DETAILS
- PLANS
- PLANS_DETAILS

Every record is recorded in `CONTACT` and `CONTACT_DATAILS` but a `CONTACT` can have 0, 1, 2 or more records in `PLANS`, Active or Cancelled.

So I did this:

```
SELECT * 
from CONTACT as c
left join PLANS as pp on pp.PKEY = c.PKEY
left join PLANS_DETAILS as pd on pd.PDKEY = p.PDKEY
inner join CONTACT_DETAILS as cd on cd.DKEY = c.DKEY
WHERE c.KEY = '267110' and PP.STATUS = 'Active'
```

"267110" have 1 active PLAN so it shows me 1 line, everything I need.

But if I put

```
WHERE c.KEY = '100003' and PP.STATUS = 'Active'
```

"100003" have 2 cancelled plans, so the result is empty. If I remove *PP.STATUS = 'Active'* , it returns me 2 identical results, but I need just one.

In resume: I need a select that returns me 1 row only. If there is an active plan, return the columns, if not, return the columns null. If someone have 1 cancelled and 1 active plan, return me only the active plan columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your question is to move the condition on `pp` to the `on` clause.

```
SELECT *
from CONTACT c inner join
     CONTACT_DETAILS cd
     on cd.DKEY = c.DKEY left join
     PLANS pp
     on pp.PKEY = c.PKEY AND PP.STATUS = 'Active' left join
     PLANS_DETAILS pd
     on pd.PDKEY = p.PDKEY
WHERE c.KEY = '267110' ;
```

In addition, when you have a series of inner and left joins, I recommend putting all the inner joins first, followed by the outer joins.  That makes it clear which joins are used for keeping records and which for filtering.

Comment: Thank you. I never used conditions in the middle of the join. Just learned a new thing.

Answer (score 1):

Just add an `ORDER BY PP.STATUS DESC` and a `TOP 1` clause, and delete the `and PP.STATUS = 'Active'`, like this

```
SELECT TOP 1 * from CONTACT as c
left join PLANS as pp on pp.PKEY = c.PKEY
left join PLANS_DETAILS as pd on pd.PDKEY = p.PDKEY
inner join CONTACT_DETAILS as cd on cd.DKEY = c.DKEY

WHERE c.KEY = '100003' 
ORDER BY PP.STATUS DESC
```

Comment: This is almost what I need, but contacts with only cancelled plans will show all the plan information, but it should not. But thank you! A mix of your help with Gordon's answer did the job!

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * 
   from CONTACT c

left join 
   (
      select * from 
        (select 
        [whatever you need from this table]
        ,row_number over(partition by [keys in this table] order by status                                            asc) rnk
      from PLANS)
      where rnk = 1
   ) pp 
   on pp.PKEY = c.PKEY

left join PLANS_DETAILS pd 
   on pd.PDKEY = p.PDKEY

inner join CONTACT_DETAILS cd 
   on cd.DKEY = c.DKEY

WHERE c.KEY = '100003'

Comment: I hope you can read this, I had a problem formatting so it is readable but essentially what will it will do will rank statuses where if there is data it will give you the active row first when you say rnk = 1 otherwise it will return the null row for that record.

Comment: Tony, thank you! This is a good idea, to join only with first row. May be useful for some other things I'm doing. But this is not the same effect as TOP 1 in the select?

Comment: 'In resume: I need a select that returns me 1 row only. If there is an active plan, return the columns, if not, return the columns null. If someone have 1 cancelled and 1 active plan, return me only the active plan columns.' - This should do just that by having the row_number in the join where you are filtering the statuses. If there is an active status it will give you that information if there is no active row it will give you whatever row it has there instead(cancelled or NULL)